# Would it be effective to crop image in yolo v4?

Tags: crop, yolo, mosaic

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxXWi.jpg)

For example as Image above, area I need is just like red box, and other section doesn't have any labels for classification/object detection.

What I think is "If I use cropped image to red box will occur better effect" because there's to much useless area without labels in original image. When mosaic augmentation used in yolo v4, It will put images together in one. And, because there's so many area without labels, data after mosaic can be useless than before.

But, This is just my guess, and I need a test to confirm it, but the lack of computing power is limiting the actual test. So the question is, Is it possible to actually improve performance if the original image is cropped in the form of a red box? Is that why I guessed correctly?

Also, my partner said that cropping is not a good choice in Yolo because it can ruin the proportion of the object, but I couldn't understand what the proportion of the object meant in Yolo. I wonder why the proportion of objects in Yolo is not suit with cropping.

Thanks for read, and have a nice day

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [Please add a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

simply you shouldn't resize the images, however, if the training/testing data set contains considerable difference among width and heights, use the data augmentation methods. Pls, follow the link for more information.
https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/800